# Завершение анимации

Tags: javascript

На  [этой страничке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/left_menu/) я сделал выезжающее слева при наведении меню. Проблема в том, что они анимация заканчивается после того, как координата left меню становится => 0. То есть между левой границей окна и меню получается зазор. Вот код

```
var menu = document.getElementById('left_menu');

menu.style.left = '-200px';

//
if (document.addEventListener) {
    addEvent = function (el, type, handler) {
        el.addEventListener(type, handler, false)
    };
} else {
    addEvent = function (el, type, handler) {
        el.attachEvent("on" + type, handler)
    };
};

//
addEvent(menu, "mouseover", function (e) {
    if (this.style.left == '-200px') {
        var element = this;
        var from = -200; // Начальная координата X
        var to = 0; // Конечная координата X
        var duration = 300; // Длительность 
        var start = new Date().getTime(); // Время старта

        setTimeout(function () {
            var now = (new Date().getTime()) - start; // Текущее время
            var progress = now / duration; // Прогресс анимации

            var result = (Math.round((to - from) * delta(progress)) + from);

            element.style.left = result + "px";

            console.log(result);

            if (progress < 1) // Если анимация не закончилась, продолжаем
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
        }, 10);
    }

    function delta(progress) {
        return progress;
    }

});

addEvent(menu, "mouseout", function (e) {
});
```

Comment: jQuery не для вас?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (Math.round((to - from) * (progress>1?1:progress)) + from);
```